# How to integrate a overlay help menu in my web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to develop an answer box element as this in my website. Which technologies I am supposed to use to achieve this result.

[image]

Comment: https://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: Please explain us what is the problem you want to solve, and what alternatives you have explored. It's not appropiate to just write a broad requirement.

Answer (score 1):

It is called text editor. There are many plugin available for including text editor in your webpage.

I would suggest you to use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) .

Comment: Thank you for understanding my question and helping.@Master Deep

Comment: My pleasure to help. If you found my answer relevant then approve it by clicking check sign on left

Answer (score 0):

A simple search in google for [html editor plugin](https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&hs=jLj&channel=fs&q=html%20editor%20plugin&oq=html%20editor%20plugin&gs_l=serp.3..0l7.3285.4205.0.4372.7.6.0.1.1.0.136.467.3j2.5.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.6.480...0i67.P3oo5nVtfp8)

Edit: the link seems not to work:
http://A%20simple%20search%20in%20google%20for%20html%20editor%20plugin:%20%20https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&hs=jLj&channel=fs&q=html%20editor%20plugin&oq=html%20editor%20plugin&gs_l=serp.3..0l7.3285.4205.0.4372.7.6.0.1.1.0.136.467.3j2.5.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.6.480...0i67.P3oo5nVtfp8